# Pause and stop a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am making a stopwatch, but I only have the start button working. When the start button is pressed it enters a loop:

```
- (void)stopwatch
{
NSInteger hourInt = [hourLabel.text intValue];
NSInteger minuteInt = [minuteLabel.text intValue];
NSInteger secondInt = [secondLabel.text intValue];

if (secondInt == 59) {
    secondInt = 0;
    if (minuteInt == 59) {
        minuteInt = 0;
        if (hourInt == 23) {
            hourInt = 0;
        } else {
            hourInt += 1;
        }
    } else {
        minuteInt += 1;
    }
} else {
    secondInt += 1;
}

NSString *hourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", hourInt];
NSString *minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", minuteInt];
NSString *secondString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", secondInt];

hourLabel.text = hourString;
minuteLabel.text = minuteString;
secondLabel.text = secondString;

CGRect hourFrame = self->hourBar.frame;
CGRect minuteFrame = self->minuteBar.frame;
CGRect secondFrame = self->secondBar.frame;

if ((NSInteger)hourFrame.size.height != hourInt) { // check if we need to modify
    hourFrame.origin.y -= ((hourInt * 10.0) - hourFrame.size.height);
    hourFrame.size.height = (hourInt * 10.0);

    self->hourBar.frame = hourFrame;
}

if ((NSInteger)minuteFrame.size.height != minuteInt) { // check if we need to modify
    minuteFrame.origin.y -= ((minuteInt * 4.0) - minuteFrame.size.height);
    minuteFrame.size.height = (minuteInt * 4.0);

    self->minuteBar.frame = minuteFrame;
}

if ((NSInteger)secondFrame.size.height != secondInt) { // check if we need to modify
    secondFrame.origin.y -= ((secondInt * 4.0) - secondFrame.size.height);
    secondFrame.size.height = (secondInt * 4.0);

    self->secondBar.frame = secondFrame;
}

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(stopwatch) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

When the stop button is pressed, I want this loop to be paused so that when the user presses start, it resumes the stopwatch.

When the reset button is pressed, I want the loop to stop and reset back to 0.

If you could make your answer as simple as possible, that would be really great because I'm only a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

Loop is the wrong construct for this type of operation. For better control, use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

A relevant example can be found [here](http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_ios_stopwatch.php).

**EDIT:**

My above answer was based on prior version of your question.
So yes, the `NSTimer` should be the controlling thing for your loop, not part of the loop.

**General implementation:**

- Start should only mark timer starting. Also note the current time from system clock. (this is optional though)
- Timer function should change value of the time variable, and compare it against the stopwatch set value. If time elapsed == set value, stop the timer using `invalidate`.
- Stop should interrupt the timer and stop it, and also the elapsed time value should be set to 0. Time Variable should be reset too, if you do not want to reuse this same time value again.

Comment: Could you write some example code, because i don't really understand much of this language?

Comment: Don't think I can simplify it any further. Also, the links posted more than explains it. Apple link also has some examples on how timers work.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the timer out of your 'loop' method and make it repeating. It should be the thing that is driving the stopwatch, not that fact that you have started your 'loop'. Then, you can stop the timer when you need to and restart it later. You can also google to find out the correct way to pause the timer (you need to change the timer to start at a specified fire date to be 100% accurate, but just knowing how many seconds are left may be enough for your case).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419736/stopwatch-counting-in-powers-of-2) it sounds like you have moved your timer outside of your `stopwatch` method. Remember, timers and loops are two *very different* things.

You can stop an `NSTimer` by calling [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) on it. Please read [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) for more details.

Comment: The method above is called when the start button is pressed. How can i turn this into an NSTimer then?

Answer (score 0):

One way that might not be completely thread safe but I just tested it and it works is to have a variable that is set to true when you click `start` and false when you click `stop`.

For example, in my `.h`, I added `@property (nonatomic) BOOL go;`, then as the first line of the method you provided, add an if check that looks like this:

```
- (void)stopwatch {
    if (!self.go) return;
    //..do the rest of your stopwatch code
    //the timer call
}
```

then my start and stop button calls look like:

```
- (void)start {
    if (!self.go) { // Do not call the stopwatch method again if it is already going.
        self.go = YES;
        [self stopwatch];
    }
}

- (void)stop {
    self.go = NO;
}
```

Comment: When it resumes, does it just start the timer again? For example, if I stopped the timer at 00:00:12  but it was one millisecond from changing to 00:00:13, would it change to 00:00:13 one millisecond after pressing start, or would it take another whole second? Hope this isn't too complicated to follow.

Comment: No, when it resumes it continues, but if in your start method in the if statement you add `self.hourLabel.text = @"0";` and the same thing for minute and second label (or just set them to whatever you initialize them to) then it will start over whenever **start** is pressed.

Comment: Did exactly as you told me but in a slightly different way. However, as I suspected, whenever I stop and press start again, it resumes from the beginning of the second. For example, (if the milliseconds were there) I stop at 00:00:12:67. Instead of resuming at 00:00:12:67, it resumes at 00:00:00:12:00. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you updating the milliseconds? I don't see it anywhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have milliseconds in my code nor do I want them, I'm just saying that with this method it doesn't resume the timer from exactly where it stopped. Instead, it starts the current second all over again. I hope you understand what I mean.